# Stop windows from auto name PCI network card

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-adapter, pci-express

When I install a pci network card windows auto names the port names and seems to completely ignore the correct ordering of the ports. Whether the ports are number 1-4 left to right or right to left on the actual hardware, windows jumbles the numbering to where it thinks port 1 is the second port on the pci card. (This is an example)

If the card is plugged into a different system, the numbering is completely different.

So in my device manager they're like this (I've simplified the names) on the left and the right side is the port ordering on the piece of hardware.

> Intel Gigabit Port #3 -----> NIC #1
>
> Intel Gigabit Port    -----> NIC #2
>
> Intel Gigabit Port #4 -----> NIC #3
>
> Intel Gigabit Port #2 -----> NIC #4

The numbering of these name is not consistent either. If I took this same network card and installed it in a different system, Windows would randomly place the numbers again. I would've assumed it numbered them based on hardware ID's but apparently not.

Is there a way to stop windows from doing this? Maybe some registry key that can stop the auto naming?

Comment: Why not rename the network card in adapter settings.

Comment: I could but I don't want too. The idea is to pop these cards in many systems and then run a configuration script that correctly sets them up. Linux has no issue with always name NIC port 1, number 1 in the system; every time. I'd have no problem renaming them manually, but when renaming them will need to be done on many system and also the need to figure out what port is what, it's an unwise use of time. There needs to be some reg key that stops this.